# javascript code doesn't work on my project

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress site for my business and I'm using Booked Plugin for Appointments, I want to send some values to mail. My code works on JsFiddle platform but doesn't work on my project, I check values on Console screen. JsFiddle shows me the values those what I want, but the project's console screen(I'm using Google Chrome) value returns 0 everytime and doesn't changes. Could you help me?

```
<input data-calendar-id="136" type="checkbox" name="single-checkbox---8012145[]" id="booked-checkbox-single-checkbox---8012145-4" class='test_23' value="CE103">
```

```
        var calculate = function() {
      var total = 0;
      // Check if a checkbox is ticked
      if ($('.test_23').is(':checked')) {
        total += 100;
      }

      // A second checkbox
      if ($('.test_24').is(':checked')) {
        total += 150;
      }

      // Display the result to the user
      $('#form-total').text('Total: $' + total);

      console.log(total);
    };

    // Calculate on page load
    calculate();


    // Recalculate when these checkboxes/radio buttons are clicked
    $('.test_23, .test_24').click(calculate);
```

[screenshot from my project's console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsyUW.png)

Comment: Could you show me the JsFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/harunsengul/7r926Lfb/

Comment: I think we need more information about your code. It's not because of your logic. For example, some other codes could prevent the click event.

Comment: How can I contact with you? I want to send the link of project, if you available. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @HarunSengul Consider posting your complete HTML here. Someone might be able to help find the issue.

Comment: https://stest.com.tr/randevu-olustur/

Comment: @YonggooNoh  Hello! Did you receive a notification, I shared the url with you.

Comment: @HarunSengul Yes i have had a look. I can not tell what's wrong in there. Sorry unless there is a backend. You can try debugging in step by step and adding console log in function see where it breaks.

Comment: First of all, I think you've added event listener on `.quform-field-11_3`, right? If so, where is `.quform-field-11_3`?

Comment: @YonggooNoh actually I don't use quform, where is that listener I don't know.

Comment: See your code: https://stest.com.tr/wp-content/plugins/quform/cache/quform.js?ver=1594726940

In that, see the line  312.

Comment: @YonggooNoh Yeap, thats my oldest JavaScript codes, I was using Quform to do same but quform plugin is not enoughable to do appointment so I was decided to use Booked Plugin. By the way that codes was working properly with Quform plugin.

Comment: You should change the class name in the source code that is looking for `.quform-field-11_3` which doesn't exist. So it doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: @YonggooNoh Booked and Quform 2 different plugins, the codes that you said custom JavaScript codes of Quform Plugin, so I dont think those are communicate each other.

Comment: If so, which .js file should I have a look? Tell me the name and I will check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219735/discussion-between-yonggoo-noh-and-harun-sengul).

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Again hello, I've create a new input below of the Appointment plugin and I've add same class name It's .harun_7 and then it worked. But when click the Appointment Button a pop-up shows up. Then I click the .harun_7 class named checbox which name is CS114, code doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions here should be self-contained and include required all information - external links are ok but only when they are included with the code itself, because external links can change or break over time and make the question invalid. The code you posted works, so there is not enough information in your question at the moment to help us help you find the problem - we are not mind readers :). You will need to do some more debugging to narrow down the problem and if you find additional relevant information, please edit the question to include it.

Answer (score -2):

You have to manually include jQuery in your project (jsfiddle may do it for you)

Comment: @always what's the difference between comment and answer, if it resolves the question?

Comment: @always how can you possibly know that, only a small fraction of the code was posted, that does not include the jQuery include, without seeing the full code it's impossible to know what's going on

Comment: I hope your assumptions are true and this is an actual answer OP did not know about. best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I also embed the cdn code of javascript to my plugin's source code but It's still same.

Comment: I knew it ! jQuery includes is NOT the issue.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Hello! Did you receive a notification, I shared the url with you.

Comment: @always hold your horses we still haven't seen the code

Comment: @bluejayke Sure no worries. Edit: I am not sure who donwvoted your working answer.

Comment: Again hello, I've create a new input below of the Appointment plugin and I've add same class name It's .harun_7 and then it worked. But when click the Appointment Button a pop-up shows up. Then I click the .harun_7 class named checbox which name is CS114, code doesn't work correctly.